# setting css display property to none or show using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to display an input error above an email field when the wrong email is inputed or when the submit button is clicked and no email is entered or an invalid email is entered .

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submitSuccess);
function submitSuccess(e) {
  const email = document.getElementsByClassName('text-and-input__inputfield');
    e.preventDefault();
    const emailInput = email[0].value;
    if( emailInput && emailInput.includes('@') && emailInput.includes('.com','.net','.edu','.biz','.xyz')){
    document.getElementById("newsletter").classList.add("hide");
    
    }
    else if( !emailInput && !emailInput.includes('@') && !emailInput.includes('.com','.net','.edu','.biz','.xyz')){
      document.getElementById("inputError").classList.add("show");
    }
    
  }
```

```css
.hide{
    display: none;
}
.inputError{
    margin-left: auto;
    display: none;
}
.labelHolder{
display: flex;
}
.show{
    display: show;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsletter"  class="newsletter_form_container ">
<form class="text-and-input__form">
        <p class="labelHolder"><label for="" class="text-and-input__label">Email address</label><small id="inputError" class="inputError">Valid email required</small></p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email@company.com" class="text-and-input__inputfield" required>
   <button  id="submit" name="submit" class="text-and-input__btn">Subcribe to monthly newletter</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

the if statement works fine but the else if statement does not work .

Comment: `display: show;` - that's not a thing; `show` is not one of the valid values for the `display` property.

Comment: The second set of 'ands' should be 'ors' (|| not &&). Having said that, I assume the last test (.com etc) is just for fun and not to be used in a real situation (think of all those county codes for example).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code, 1 `show` is not a valid `display` attribute, replace it with `block` as `display: block` and secondly the `elseif` should account for the conditions separately to check if any of the `condition` is `true`, display the error as shown in snippet.

```js
document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', submitSuccess);

function submitSuccess(e) {
    const email = document.getElementsByClassName('text-and-input__inputfield');
    e.preventDefault();
    const emailInput = email[0].value;
    if (emailInput && emailInput.includes('@') && emailInput.includes('.com', '.net', '.edu', '.biz', '.xyz')) {
        document.getElementById("newsletter").classList.add("hide");
    } else if (!emailInput || !emailInput.includes('@') || !emailInput.includes('.com', '.net', '.edu', '.biz', '.xyz')) {
        document.getElementById("inputError").classList.add("show");
    }
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.inputError {
    margin-left: auto;
    display: none;
}

.labelHolder {
    display: flex;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="newsletter"  class="newsletter_form_container ">
    <form class="text-and-input__form">
        <p class="labelHolder"><label for="" class="text-and-input__label">Email address</label><small id="inputError" class="inputError">Valid email required</small></p>
        <input type="email" placeholder="email@company.com" class="text-and-input__inputfield" required>
        <button  id="submit" name="submit" class="text-and-input__btn">Subcribe to monthly newletter</button>
    </form>
</div>
```